# Add a banner message about Yom Tov?

Tags: feature-request

Should we post a site banner along the lines of "Most participants here will be offline until Sunday", for the benefit of non-Jews (and perhaps some Jews) who come here with questions?  (This question is prompted by Rosh Hashana and today's questions from new users, but we'll have two more three-day outages coming up soon, so this question is not just about the current one.)

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2044132#2044132

Comment: Oh good; others are way ahead of me.  (Chat doesn't play well with my browser affordances for accessibility, so it didn't occur to me to bring it up there.)

Comment: Well, this is the right place to bring it up anyway. I was merely pointing you and others to the views already expressed in chat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a discussion in chat (linked above) with the outcome that there won't be a banner for fear of attracting trouble while nobody's home, but other SE moderators will keep an eye out for anything egregious.

(I posted this answer meaning to resolve the question, but there's a two-day waiting period for accepting your own answer.  If somebody else wants to cut/paste this into an answer in the next hour or two, go for it and I'll accept that and delete this.)